# restrict "Remember password" window or "autocomplete=off" in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, firefox3.6

I want to set "autocomplete="off" property in **Mozilla Firefox 3.6 for a single form on a web page not for complete web application**.
But it seems that 3.6 version does not have autocomplete property. I am able to restrict the firefox to show  "Remember Password" window on Firefox 11.

In Firefox 11, my JavaScript is:

```
changeForm.obj.autocomplete = "off";
```

But it is not working in Firefox 3.6

Please suggest how can I restrict Firefox 3.6 to show "Remember Password" window.

Comment: The way I understand boolean attributes, the value of `autocomplete` should be either `""` or `"autocomplete"`.

Comment: @Jack `autocomplete` is not a boolean. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion